# using paste0 within dplyr::filter function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having some trouble using paste0 within the dplyr::filter  function and would appreciate some help. I have pasted the code below. When I run it my the result I am getting has 0 rows instead of 2.

```
sig_time_hours_results1 <- data.frame (ID  = c("value_1", "value_2", "value3", "value4"),
                  Pval_time_hours8h = c(1.00, 0.005, 0.006, 0.2)
                  )

hour = "8h" 
Pval_time_hours <- paste0("Pval_time_hours", hour)
sig_time_hours_results2 <- dplyr::filter(sig_time_hours_results1, paste0(Pval_time_hours) < 0.05)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `.data` with `[[`

```
dplyr::filter(sig_time_hours_results1, .data[[Pval_time_hours]] < 0.05)
```

-output

```
      ID Pval_time_hours8h
1 value_2             0.005
2  value3             0.006
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great. I have also replaced paste0 and tried using get and its working as well '''sig_time_hours_results2 <- dplyr::filter(sig_time_hours_results1, get(Pval_time_hours) < 0.05)'''

Comment: @akrun why not just `sig_time_hours_results1 %>% 
  filter(Pval_time_hours8h < 0.05)`

Comment: @TarJae probably because the OP stored the column name in a string and want to use it

Comment: I am using it within a function, and the Pval_time_hours will not be the same

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more careful when using strings as column names. You can't just use `paste0() to turn a string into a column name. One way to do this would be to use tidyseslectors. For example

```
sig_time_hours_results2 <- sig_time_hours_results1 |> 
    filter(if_all(Pval_time_hours, ~.x < 0.05))
```

Even though we are only checking one column, we still use `if_all` to make sure the filters hold.